# RCConnection Error: setSDP Error: Failed to set remote offer sip: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint

Tags: android, webrtc, restcomm, dtls

I am using Restcomm's Android SDK and trying to configure it to our servers, but getting the following error:

```
RCConnection Error: setSDP Error: Failed to set remote offer sip: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint
```

But when I changing back to Restcomm servers it works fine.

I have tried to search it at Google and Git, but the solutions offered there did not help. Any idea how to solve the issue ( please explain in details since I am new in WebRTC ) ?

**EDIT:**

In case when I call from mobile to web or from the web to web it works fine. The problem occurs only when the mobile tries to accept the call.

Comment: Check if SDP generated by your web client contains a line starting with `a=fingerprint` (see https://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/). If not then it does not support DTLS.

Comment: The problem is that the mobile sends all the data ( DTLS too ), but in the receiving part I see an empty fingerprint field.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure your server supports DTLS-SRTP for the Media and ICE Lite procedures.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you say how can I check it ? ( sorry for such a noob question )

Comment: I have checked and it supports